# search files in current directory whose name do not contain "txt" in linux

Tags: linux, shell, find-util

I know how to find files with suffix `.txt` in the current directory:
`find *.txt`

How do I invert this?

I am new to Linux, so please help. Thanks!

Comment: @John1024: You're probably thinking of `find -name '*.txt'`; `find *.txt`, due to using an _unquoted_ glob, will only match `*.txt` files in the _current_ directory (because it is the _shell_ performing the globbing), and pass the matching files as arguments to `find` (hypothetically, if there were `*.txt` _directories_, `find` _would_ recurse into them, listing _all_ files there).

Comment: @mklement0 You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the current directory, and your shell is bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*.txt)
```

[reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Answer (score 2):

find in current file not recursive

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*.txt"
```

Comment: @NickKitto: Seems like a valid answer to me; what makes you think it's not?

Answer (score 0):

```
find ! -name  "*.txt"
```

or

```
find -not -name "*.txt"
```